# Ruby on Rails form checkbox without model?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I want to create a plain checkbox element in my form that I will reference in the index method of my controller. The boolean value will determine one of two scopes I wish to set for use in my filterrific initialization. The checkbox value will not be used for form submission, and will not be persisted in the database, it is simply for determining if the user wishes to see 'closed' tickets when the  - all - option is chosen (the default is to exclude closed tickets.)

I am having a terrible time wrapping my head around all the search results I have been reading. Might someone feel sorry for me and tell me how to proceed? It would be much appreciated.

Thanks for taking the time to read my question, I do value your attention.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

if I read your question you need check_box_tag [this is the reference](https://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/FormTagHelper/check_box_tag) and below is sample code

```
<%= check_box_tag 'receive_email', 'no',false, class: "name" %>
```

information:

- receive_email = just local variable name
- 'no' = sample value, you can fill this with integer / string
- false = default checkbox condition when rendered

Comment: Do I need to define the field (as shown in your example) receive_email in my model using the attr_accessor method? And/or instantiate the variable in my controller?

Comment: no need to setup model, as my information above receive_email just variable that hold the value

Comment: One more question, and thank you immensely for your responses, in my controller when I want to reference the value of 'receive_email' do I do so as an object :receive_email or @receive_email? Please pardon the fundamentalness of my questions, web frameworks are not my first language and I have huge knowledge gaps

Comment: you can check it with params[:receive_email]

Comment: Floating on a cloud right now, thank you SO MUCH for your assistance! It's the little things that seem to fluster me the most!

Answer (score 1):

This information was very useful to me.

An example where it use a checkbox but don't want it included as part of a model and not be saved to the database.

**Model:**
It's all about `attr_accessor` and `attr_accessible`

```
attr_accessor           :checkbox_checked
attr_accessible         :checkbox_checked
```

**View**

```
...
<%= f.check_box :checkbox_checked %>
  <span class="small_label">See closed tickets?</span>
...
```

**Controller**

```
...
    if params[:user][:checkbox_checked] == "1"
        # do something
    end
...
```

source: [How create a virtual attribute in Rails](https://agilewarrior.wordpress.com/2011/09/17/how-create-create-a-virtual-attribute-in-rails/)

It is also important to be clear and review the [**strong params**](https://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/action_controller_overview.html#strong-parameters)

Hope this helps, it was for me, I would like to explain more in detail, but I am new to this topic.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to just add it with the  `check_box` method on the form element.

```
<%= form_with: @model do |form| %>
  <%= form.email :field_on_model %>
  <%= form.check_box :field_not_on_model %>
  ... 
<% end %>
```

Inside of the params hash you will see:  `{"field_on_model" => "travis@example.com", "field_not_on_model" => "0"}`

So you should be able to do whatever you need with `params['field_not_on_model']`.